# Convert a date stored as String to Date and extract only the year in it

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to look for an answer for a while but couldn't find one corresponding to mine.

I have stored the Date Of Birth of a person in `firebase` AS a String. I've retrieve it correctly using `onDataChange`. But the problem arises when i need to calculate the age of that person and i can't extract the year from that String. Can anyone help me?

Thank you

[image: Here is the data stored in firebase]

Comment: Yes, don't save a date as a string ;) Calculating and sorting is much more difficult

Comment: Thanks, Followed the steps below and solved the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split your String and take the last value like this:

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(date.split("/")[2]);
```

Comment: No I've tried but it doesn't work. Here is my code

 myDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            Override
            public void onDataChange(NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                additionalDetails AD = dataSnapshot.getValue(additionalDetails.class);

                String dob = AD.getDOB();

                int year = Integer.parseInt(dob.split("/")[2]);

                testDate.setText(year);
            }

            Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

Comment: Well yeah... setText method accepts String so you should put date.split("/")[2] there

Comment: I've solved the problem.

Since setText does not display int value, we need to convert it by using **String.valueOf()**

Thank you very much!